# Exporting post info into a formatted table and into MailChimp as automated as possible

Tags: rss, export, plugin-mailchimp

This is a complex one, and I'm ok if not every aspect of it can be automated but I'd like to try to get as close as possible.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm building a job site and I want to be able to send new jobs every week to signed up users through MailChimp (I'll happily consider another email sender if someone recommends one that can achieve what I'm trying to do).
I'd like the newsletter/job alert email to be formatted like so(|| indicate column separators):

Title Job1||Company Job1||Country Job1
Title Job2||Company Job2||Country Job2

The title of each job should be a hyperlink to the full job page on the site.

**What I've tried:** Using mailchimp's RSS function I'm able to build an automated newsletter that includes all new jobs. BUT, I'm struggling with two aspects:

1. I can't extract the country and company info from the RSS feed; these are custom fields and MailChimp does not seem to offer that functionality. I can only get the title, author, date, excerpt and full text as far as I can tell.
2. I can't figure out how to format the individual fields from one RSS item (im my case each job) into columns.

The only thing I can think of right now is a convoluted series of transformations, using WP All Export to export the right custom fields into csv, then transforming the CSV into HTML with some custom code, then importing that HTML into a custom campaign in MailChimp, but I don't know if I'd ever be able to automate that.

I'd really appreciate any advice that can point me in the right direction on this!!

Comment: Getting this into a Mailchimp campaign in a table format is the bit I think may be a step too far. What just popped into my mind was that you could customise the RSS title output to include (Title | Company | Country) and Mailchimp will use that quite happily but it could become untidy. Alternatively if the company and country were categories, Mailchimp has RSS merge tags for categories which could be worth a look? I think you may still end up with a list rather than a table though... thats my ten cents worth if its any help?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The merge tags don't pick those fields up as categories for whatever reason, even though they are in the feed.